# Fastest way searching specific files

Tags: c#, file-system, search

I got thousands of files with a specific file extension in thousands of sub folders. Now, what is the fastest way to search with a pattern? I tried the method `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(rootfolder)` (~8 minutes) and a recursive custom method (~5 minutes).

```
 private void WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo dr, string searchname)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;
        try
        {
            files = dr.GetFiles(searchname + ".*");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                allFiles.Add(fi);
            }
            subDirs = dr.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo di in subDirs)
            {
                WalkDirectoryTree(di, searchname);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: What type is `allFiles` ? Do you need `FileInfo` or the filename ?

Comment: It's a List<FileInfo>. I need the FileInfo, not only the filename.

Comment: An how do you use the List<> ? Do you just iterate over the entries and process them in some way?

Comment: Yes that's it. It's not really relevant I think.

Comment: yes it is relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try parallelization. Instead of:

> ```
> foreach (DirectoryInfo di in subDirs)
> {
>     WalkDirectoryTree(di, searchname);
> }
> ```

Do

```
Parallel.ForEach(subDirs, dir => WalkDirectoryTree(dir, searchname));
```

Notice that by doing this `allFiles` will be accessed concurrently so change your collection to a ConcurrentBag.

Comment: @greenhoorn I would be glad to hear the improvements you had after the replacement.

Comment: I will share it as soon as I test it. Could take 2 weeks :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still takes 2 minutes but that's significantly faster than before. I would say 2 minutes for millions of files is acceptable :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` and therefor if you access them by the enumerator they will be evaluated when they are accessed.

```
private void WalkDirectoryTree(DirectoryInfo dr, string searchname)
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in FindFiles(dr, searchname + ".*"))
    {
        // process file
        allFiles.Add(file);
    }
}
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> FindFiles(DirectoryInfo startDirectory, string pattern)
{
     return startDirectory.EnumerateFiles(pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
```

Comment: So the method GetFiles() does some more processing than EnumerateFiles(), do I get this right? I will give this a try too, thanks.

Comment: No, but EnumerateFiles returns the single FileInfo's only if they are accessed (foreach... or calling .ToList())

Comment: @Heslacher Lazyness does not solve slowness. And in this scenario it will be the same as a non lazy algorithm because you are evaluating all items imediatly and putting them in a list (wich can be done. like you said, with the ToList() method).